# Disable TLSv1.0 in Nginx Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl

We have had trustwave scan done of are server and its telling us to disable TLSv1.

Going into the domain config I have removed the support for TLSv1 ie.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name .domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com/428394/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.domain.com/428394/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.domain.com-error.log error;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://428394_app/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Handle Web Socket Connections
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

But the scan from trustwave is still showing TSLv1 support.

The nginx version is

```
nginx version: nginx/1.11.5
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-Rrk92d/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Is there something I am missing?

Thank you for your support

Comment: Is that the only TLS server block? If not please be aware that many security scanners (also) connect to only the IP-address (without SNI) and settings other than the domain config may apply i.e. those from other server blocks or the main http context...

Comment: There is around 5 other domains on the server.. All of them have had TLSv1 removed.

Comment: Does the `default_server` also have TLSv1 removed?